# Disable QWebEngineView access to QFileDialog

Tags: pyqt, pyqt5, qwebview, qfiledialog

I'm trying to develop a browser that allows downloads but disables all ways for uploading something to the internet. I developed the browser with PyQt5 but I can't figure out how to disable the FileDialog (ex when clicking on add an attachment in Gmail). I already set up settings disabling things like LocalContentCanAccessRemoteUrls and LocalContentCanAccessFileUrls among other flags. I also subclassed the QWebEnginePage and modified the "chooseFile" function without any luck. Below you can see my code, [here you can find the UI and resources file](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0By_Of3KgrnMgWWt6czd2MC1ad3M).

```
# Python import
import sys

# PYQT Imports
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets, QtWebEngineWidgets
# from QtWebEngineWidgets.QWebEngineView import QWebEngineView

# UI IMPORT
import UI_Sailor


class WebPage(QtWebEngineWidgets.QWebEnginePage):
    def chooseFile(self, frame=None, path=''):
        print ('Called this')
        return


class Sailor(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, UI_Sailor.Ui_Sailor):

    def __init__(self):
        super(self.__class__, self).__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
        # self.setWindowIcon(QtGui.QIcon(':/Icons/Icons/Icon_Small.png'))
        self.setWindowTitle('Sailor - 1.0.0')

        glob_settings = QtWebEngineWidgets.QWebEngineSettings.globalSettings()
        self.setWebSettings(glob_settings)

        self.create_connections()

    def setWebSettings(self, object_settings):
        print ('Called')
        # Global web settings
        object_settings.setAttribute(1, True)  # JaveScript
        object_settings.setAttribute(3, False)  # Clipboard (JaveScript)
        object_settings.setAttribute(5, False)  # Local Storage
        object_settings.setAttribute(6, False)  # LocalContentCanAccessRemoteUrls
        object_settings.setAttribute(7, False)  # XSSAuditingEnabled
        object_settings.setAttribute(9, False)  # LocalContentCanAccessFileUrls
        object_settings.setAttribute(11, True)  # ScrollAnimatorEnabled
        object_settings.setAttribute(14, True)  # FullScreenSupportEnabled

        # Check that the options are applied
        # print (object_settings.testAttribute(1))  # JaveScript
        # print (object_settings.testAttribute(2))  # JaveScript
        # print (object_settings.testAttribute(3))  # Clipboard (JaveScript)
        # print (object_settings.testAttribute(5))  # Local Storage
        # print (object_settings.testAttribute(6))  # LocalContentCanAccessRemoteUrls
        # print (object_settings.testAttribute(7))  # XSSAuditingEnabled
        # print (object_settings.testAttribute(9))  # LocalContentCanAccessFileUrls
        # print (object_settings.testAttribute(11))  # ScrollAnimatorEnabled
        # print (object_settings.testAttribute(14))  # FullScreenSupportEnabled

    def create_connections(self):
        self.TXT_Address.returnPressed.connect(self.web_load_url)
        # self.WEB_View.urlChanged.connect(self.debug)

    def web_load_url(self):
        # Creates the proper url
        url_base = str(self.TXT_Address.text())
        url_clean = self.url_handler(url_base)
        # Loads the url
        # self.WEB_View.setUrl(QtCore.QUrl(url_clean))
        self.WEB_View.setPage(WebPage(self.WEB_View))
        self.WEB_View.load(QtCore.QUrl(url_clean))

        self.setWebSettings(self.WEB_View.settings())


    def debug(self):
        print ('called')


    def url_handler(self, url):
        if 'http' not in url:
            return 'http://{}'.format(url)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    form = Sailor()
    form.show()
    app.exec_()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You defined the wrong method in the `WebPage` class. It looks like you may have used the signature from the `QtWebKit.QWebPage` class, rather than the one from the [QWebEnginePage](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwebenginepage.html#chooseFiles) class. Here is a minimal working example:

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets, QtWebEngineWidgets

class WebPage(QtWebEngineWidgets.QWebEnginePage):
    def chooseFiles(self, mode, oldfiles, mimetypes):
        print('Called this')
        return []

class Window(QtWebEngineWidgets.QWebEngineView):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Window, self).__init__()
        self.setPage(WebPage(self))
        self.setHtml('<input type="file">')

if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Window()
    window.setGeometry(600, 100, 400, 200)
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```